# Why is Blender rendering my vertical image distorted?

Tags: rendering, camera, eevee-render-engine

I want to render out an vertical image of my model. It should be complete visible but with no unused space.

I've changed the Dimensions of the output like that:
[image]

In Blender the camera view looks now like that:
[image]

but the output looks like that:
[image]

How can I print out the expected result?

Comment: They look identical to me. What is the issue?

Comment: You changed the aspect ratio.

Comment: @rob its distored. It looks like the model is squashed

Comment: **Don't touch the aspect ratio settings unless you are rendering anamorphic pixels**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @rjg's comment, your aspect ratio (just below the image dimensions) makes your image's pixels non-square, thus squashing the final result.